# Name convention for private methods C# - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, visual-studio-2017

I have just installed a new version of Visual Studio 2017 and the studio recommends me, that I should use Pascal case for private methods (void PrivateMethod()). Everything is okay, it's just the name convention. I use usually Camel case (void privateMethod()). I don't intend change my style.

However why does the Visual Studio 2017 generate the private methods for FormsApp wrong by their name convention? -> private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) Then it recommends me I should change the name to Button3_Click.

It's nothig important but I'm just curious about that. Probably a mistake on the Microsoft's side?

Comment: Im no expert on why they do that and i see your point. But to ease a little confusion, when i studied development i had to compare Camel casing with Pascals casing. eg. thisIsCamelCasing, ThisIsPascalsCasing.
See here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It is most probably due to lack of communication / disagreement between different departments at Microsoft.  The department which is in charge of Visual Studio recommendations, vs. the department which is in charge of the WinForms Designer.

Comment: Well, the easy explanation is that the handler naming convention is `{control name}_{event name}`. The control is probably named `button3`, therefore the handler keeps the variable name even if it violates the general naming convention.

Comment: @InBetween Of Course, that's absolutly true. I'm stupid, that I didn't realize it. Thank you. :)

Comment: Yes, the control should be called `QuitButton` and then the rest follows/

Comment: @Henk Holterman: But this will violate the guideline for fields -> should be camelCase

Comment: That especially applies to private fields. Public fields should use PascalCasing. Controls are usually public (but it's a setting somewhere).

Comment: Ok. But I have never used public controls.

Answer (score 3):

VS 2017 lets you specify the code style you want.

Look for Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Naming

The 'Manage Styles' button lets you add a "lowerPascalCase" style, and the '+' button lets you add a new rule that uses that style for Private Methods.  The 'Severity' column lets you determine how draconian the enforcement of the rule should be.

Make sure to sort your new rule above the 'Non-Field Members' in the list.

Comment: what would a protected method fall under? i tried private method but it doesn't cover the protected method